# Make element transparent through multiple parent elements?

Tags: css, html, background, transparent, mask

Is there some trick to make an element transparent through it's parent element's BG and show the body BG for instance.

Example:

```
<body style="background: url(galaxy.jpg)">
<div style="background: black;">
<a href="#" style="background:super-transparent;">Click Me!</a>
</div>
</body>
```

So even though it's parent element has a black background, it would still show through to the body background. Is this possible?

Comment: I've seen this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nLa8oaq0/21/ but think it's very clunky and wouldn't work for dynamic elements.

Comment: Not possible without javascript.

Comment: What kind of javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to all element that must be transparent

```
    <a href="#" class="super-transparent">Click Me!</a>
```

Then you can import JQuery and add this code:

```
$(".super-transparent").css("background", $("body").css("background-image")).each(function(index, element) {
    var position = $(this).position();
    $(this).css("background-position", "-"+position.left+"px "+"-"+position.top+"px");
});
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35bLdtvj/4/

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't always good, but i hope this time i'm helping you for real. This creates some kindof "hole" in the parent's background, so body's background is visible through the links.